# Backup failed because ZipArchive::close(): Can't open file: Permission denied in Laravel-backup from spatie

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

The following command fails for some users, but not for root:

```
php artisan backup:run
Backup failed because ZipArchive::close(): Can't open file: Permission denied.
```

I don't understand, how exactly do I fix directory permissions, for which directory. Permissions are set to 777 for all directories.

Comment: Any updates on this?

Answer (score 1):

You have file/directory with incorrect permission/ownership in the files you want to backup. Exclude this file/dir in the backup settings or change permissions.

Comment: I have changed ownership to `laradock:laradock` in all possible directories, including: `storage/`, `backups/`, `backups-temp/` & `/tmp` and still get that `Backup failed because: ZipArchive::close(): Can't open file: Permission denied.` error. However, if I execute `artisan backup:run` as `root`, it does work. But the automated process, doesn't. What am I missing? Any ideas or workaround?